# Android App Using AppAuth Demo by OpenId and 3rd Party OAuth2 Provider - response gets lost

Tags: java, android, oauth-2.0, appauth

I'm creating an Android App using Java in Android Studio that will need to use OAuth2 to communicate with a 3rd-Party provider ([Furkot, mobile method](https://help.furkot.com/widgets/furkot-api.html)) to gain authorization for subsequent API calls.

Using Open Id's AppAuth demo application (https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android) the demo app successfully:

- Sends the authentication REQUEST for a TOKEN from the Furkot Server
- Prompts user to login to Furkot
- Prompts user to allow read-only access to Furkot data
- [Furkot successfully sets the application as an allowed application]
- Receives the RESPONSE with the TOKEN value at the redirect_uri in a parameterized URL
- Shows the full responseUri value in the RedirectUriReceiverActivity during debug.

Somewhere between the

**RedirectUriReceiverActivity**

and the

**TokenActivity.onStart()**
AuthorizationResponse response = AuthorizationResponse.fromIntent(getIntent());

the code decides that the response is NULL so errors.

And I can't figure out where it's doing that to be able to troubleshoot further. Debugging and stepping into this section gets me nothing of value to my brain.

~~~~~~~
Caveat: while I have 13+ years experience developing C# .NET applications, this is my first Android app and first time working in Java. So I'm swimming a bit out of my comfort zone.
~~~~~~~

If anyone has experience -- *very specifically with the Open Id AppAuth demo application* -- and can assist, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Lead maintainer of AppAuth here - I'm not familiar with Furkot but I suspect from that they may not be handling the auto-generated _state_ parameter correctly (since they make no mention of it in their documentation). If you could post a full example of the authorization request URI that AppAuth is sending, and the full URI of the redirect response, I can help. Also, check your logs to see if the library is logging why it is rejecting the response.

Comment: I have a similar problem using Azure b2c authentication. While debugging I can see the response in the uristring and ssp data fields but they're not detected as part of the extra response.

Comment: OK, so apologies for no response to your responses here! We went on a 3-week motorcycle vacation to Alaska shortly after this -- for which I was making this app -- and by the time we got back, I'd entirely forgotten about having submitted this question. {doh!} Leaving it here though as I'll probably want to revisit it if/when I pick up that app development again. :0)